# Declare scalar variable c#

Tags: c#, sql

When I execute my code I have this error :

> The scalar variable "@qte" must be declared.

```
        Connection newconnection = new Connection();
        newconnection.Connection_Today();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.Connection = Connection.conn;

        comm.CommandText = "UPDATE F_DOCLIGNE SET DO_DateLivr = @date, DL_Qte = @qte, DL_Remise01REM_Valeur = @remise, DL_PrixUnitaire = @pu, DL_MontantHT = (@pu - ((@remise * @pu) / 100)) * @qte where AR_Ref = @code";

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("qte", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("remise", SqlDbType.Int);

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", textBox_livr.Text);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@pu", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox_prix.Text;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox_art.Text;

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I try `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qte", DL_Qte)` I have the error

> The name 'DL_Qte' don't exist in the current context

My variables @qte and @remise have the value of the fields in my database and they are used to calculate an amount.

How can i declare scalar variables without doing procedures?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "@qte and @remise have the value of the fields in my database"? If you dont want to change `DL_Qte` or `DL_Remise01REM_Valeur`, just drop them from your `UPDATE` statement...

Comment: You did not add a parameter named `@qte` to `comm.Parameters`.

Comment: I don't want to remove @qte and @remise from my `UPDATE`, they are used to calculate an amount. When I try `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qte", DL_Qte);` it don't work

Comment: Your UPDATE command is modifying the values of the DL_Qte & DL_Remise01REM_Valeur  fields - if the correct values are already in the fields in the database then use the fields in the calculations

Comment: I think creating a procedure that calculates the amount and I'll call in the program

Comment: `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qte", DL_Qte);` cannot work if `DL_Qte` is not a variable in your **C# code**.

Answer (score 1):

You created an instance of the parameter "@qte" (Variable "param") with

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("qte", SqlDbType.Int);
```

but didn't add this "param" with comm.Parameters.Add, so that's why this parameter is missing.

so you should do:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: He should also include the `@` in the parameter name literal.

Answer (score 0):

If, for instance, @qte is a value that already comes from the database, its not a variable. You use variables to send values from your code to the db. In your case (if i understood right) you need to rewrite the update statement:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = (select 1) where otherecolum = @var
```

Where offcourse, you have to provide the 'select 1' implementation to query the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you imply in your question, you want to use the values of the DL_Qte & DL_Remise01REM_Valeur fields, rather than update them - you can use them directly if they are in the same row you are updating :

```
comm.CommandText = @"UPDATE F_DOCLIGNE SET DO_DateLivr = @date, DL_PrixUnitaire = @pu, 
        DL_MontantHT = (@pu - ((DL_Remise01REM_Valeur * @pu) / 100)) * DL_Qte 
        where AR_Ref = @code";
```